# Connecting to Mongo on host using `host.docker.internal`

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have a server running in a docker container which is trying to connect to a mongo database on the host system. To do so, I use the following connection string: `mongodb://host.docker.internal:27017/db_name`.
This works fine on my Mac, but when running it on Ubuntu, it stops working for me. My initial thought was that `host.docker.internal` did not get resolved properly. But it does! I verified this using a server on the host to which I was able to connect from the container. Also, the error message does mention the resolved ip:

```
connect ECONNREFUSED 172.17.0.1:27017
```

I run my container as follows:

```bash
sudo docker run --env-file ./.env --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway image:latest
```

My guess is that I need to allow connections coming from `172.17.0.1` in my mongo config. But if that's the case, why does it work on Mac?

I am certain Mongo is running on the correct port on the host:

```
net: { bindIp: '127.0.0.1', port: 27017 }
```

So I am not entirely sure what is going on here. Could someone explain why I can't connect to the host's mongo database and what would be the best way to solve it without compromising any security?

Comment: Have you verified that mongodb is running on your host? Does `ss -tln` show something listening on port 27017? Do you have any firewall rules in place that could be blocking the connection?

Comment: @larsks Yes! My apologies for not mentioning that in the original post. I will add that information

Answer (score 0):

After looking more into this, I did had to add `172.17.0.1` to my `mongod.conf` file to make it work:

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1, 172.17.0.1
```

This makes sense, as before it would only allow localhost connections.
As for why it did work on my Mac, the config did allow connections from that address already!